# How to connect 2 Port to 1 Port in repeating child schematic on Altium?

Tags: circuit-design, usb, schematics, altium, usb-pd

I just want to connect two child schematics with repeating one. I want to connect PA CC pins to one child, and PB CC pins to the other child USB Interface. Trying to wire but it always shorting CC1 pins to repeating schematics. Is there any way to wire them uniquely? How can I solve this issue?

[image: USB PD Controller]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use REPEAT(CC1) on the Sheet Symbol.

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: It works thank you so much!

Comment: @devscg - My pleasure, good luck with your project!